# equivalence of two logical identities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(a) (P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (Q ∧ ¬P)

(b) (P ∨ Q) ∧ ¬(P ∧ Q)

According to the book (How to prove it by Polya) a and b are equivalent. My question is can either one of them be converted into the other's form using the laws (DeMorgans etc.) If not how would you explain how they are equivalent without using truth tables. I'm sure they are equivalent, but I want to understand in my head "the why".

Comment: Have you *tried* using laws?  Obviously it can be proven.  They wouldn't just state something if it wasn't.  If P and not Q then P or Q, and also not P and Q.  Otherwise if Q and not P than also both P or Q an not P and Q.  So a implies b.  If b is true an P is true then Q is false so P and not Q.  Or if P is false then Q must be true.  So Q and not P.  Either way P and not Q, or Q and not P.  So b implies a.

Comment: yes, I tried the laws but I was not able to make them equivalent. I tried to rewrite your proof into logical notation but was not able to(i am not able to follow it either). I lost it when you said "a implies b".Can you write it in logical notation please.

Comment: I have rewritten using the conditional law and some others as:
[(P → Q ) ∧ (Q → P)] is equivalent to [(¬P → Q ) ∧ (P → ¬Q)]

There must be something wrong with what i rewrote because it is not equivalent

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it using Natural Deduction, Tableaux, Hilbert-system, etc... Using Natural Deduction:

$(P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (Q ∧ ¬P) \to (P ∨ Q) ∧ ¬(P ∧ Q)$. Eliminate the implication and you need prove $(P ∨ Q) ∧ ¬(P ∧ Q)$ from $(P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (Q ∧ ¬P)$. To prove $(P ∨ Q) ∧ ¬(P ∧ Q)$, you need prove (a) $(P ∨ Q)$ and  (b) $¬(P ∧ Q)$. To prove (a) $(P ∨ Q)$, use elimination of disjunction in $(P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (Q ∧ ¬P)$, you need prove $(P ∨ Q)$ from (i) $(P ∧ ¬Q)$ and from (ii) $(Q ∧ ¬P)$. To (i) eliminate the conjunction, you have $P$, introduce the disjunction and you have $(P ∨ Q)$. To (ii) eliminate the conjunction and you have $Q$, introduce the disjunction and you have $(P ∨ Q)$. To (b), you need prove $¬(P ∧ Q)$, eliminate the negation and you need prove $\bot$ from $(P ∧ Q)$, introduce the disjunction again, in the first step use $Q$ and $\neg Q$, in the second step use $P$ and $\neg P$.

Answer (score 0):

$P \land \lnot Q \implies P$

$P \implies P \lor Q$

i) So $P \land \lnot   Q \implies P \lor Q$.

$P \land \lnot Q \implies \lnot Q$

$\lnot Q \implies \lnot(P \land Q)$.

ii) So $P \land \lnot Q \implies P\lnot(P \land Q)$.

1) by i) and ii) Therefore $P \land \lnot A \implies (P \lor Q) \land \lnot(P \land Q)$.

$Q \land \lnot P \implies Q$

$Q \implies P \lor Q$.

iii) So $Q \land \lnot P \implies P \lor Q$

$Q \land \lnot P \implies \lnot P$.

$\lnot P \implies \lnot (P \land Q)$.

iv) So $Q \land \lnot P \implies \lnot(P \land Q)$.

2) by iii) and iv) therefore $Q\land \lnot P \implies (P \lor Q) \land \lnot(P \land Q)$.

A) By 1) and 2) $(P\land \lnot Q) \lor (Q \land \lnot P) \implies  (P \lor Q) \land \lnot(P \land Q)$.

Or a) \implies b).

That's half:

=======

$(P \lor Q) \land \lnot(P \land Q) \iff [P \land \lnot(P \land Q)] \lor [Q \land \lnot(P \land Q)]$

vi) $P \land \lnot(P \land Q) \implies P \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \implies (P \land \lnot P) \lor (P \land \lnot Q) \implies False \lor (P \land \lnot Q) \implies (P \land \lnot Q)$.

vii) Similarly $Q \land \lnot(P \land Q)\implies (Q\land \lnot P) \lor (Q \land \lnot Q) \implies Q \land \lnot P)$.

So combining vi) and vii) $[P \land \lnot(P \land Q)] \lor [Q \land \lnot(P \land Q)] \implies (P \land \lnot Q)\lor Q \land \lnot P)$

so as $[P \land \lnot(P \land Q)] \lor [Q \land \lnot(P \land Q)] \iff (P \lor Q) \land \lnot(P\land Q) $ we have $(P \lor Q) \land \lnot(P\land Q) \implies (P \land \lnot Q)\lor Q \land \lnot P)$.

Or $b \implies a$.

That's the other half.

========
$a$ and $b$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

$$(P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Distribution)}$$

$$(P \lor \neg P) \land (P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor \neg P) \land (\neg Q \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Complement)}$$

$$\top \land (P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor \neg P) \land \top \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$(P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor \neg P) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Commutation)}$$

$$(P \lor Q) \land (\neg P \lor \neg Q) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (DeMorgan)}$$

$$(P \lor Q) \land \neg (P \land Q)$$